# According to math-quiz.co.uk the $x^3+12x^2−19x=−20$ factorised is $(x−4)(x+5)(x+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

My answer in red under "Your answer" isn't my answer I just had to chose something since it was a multiple choice

My working to check if it's correct

$(x−4)(x+5)(x+1)$

$(x^2-4x+5x-20)(x+1)$

$x^3+x^2-4x^2-4x+5x^2+5x-20x-20$

$x^3+2x^2-19x-20$

Am I wrong or is math-quiz.co.uk wrong?

Comment: Both could be wrong... Just put $x=-1$ and check what you get.

Comment: Your factorization of $x^3+12x^2-19x-20$ is wrong (the polynomial has no real roots). There's a typo in the question online, it should be "factor $x^3+2x^2-19x-20$" instead.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM It's multiple choice, all the choices were wrong lol

Comment: * has no **trivial** real roots is what I meant.

Comment: Actually, the polynomial $x^3+12x^2-19x+20$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$ - for example, because it has no roots in $\Bbb F_3$

Comment: When you first start factoring polynomials, I would recommend plugging something simple like $x=0$ into the equation and seeing if your answer is correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit=I hadn't checked your answer, I just saw their answer is wrong.

Maths quiz is wrong, but your answer is wrong too. The real answer is a lot more complicated, and includes a factor with no real solutions.

Your proof that their answer is wrong is correct though.

Comment: Your answer is totally wrong.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM in what way is this answer wrong? Winkworth's factorisation $x^3+2x^2-19x-20=(x-4)(x+5)(x+1)$ is correct.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM sorry I just saw their answer was wrong, I didn't check his answer.

Comment: @almagest you have looked at it wrong, it is 12x^2 and +20 not -20

Comment: @Jenkins. The OP was given a multiple choice question. Every answer available to pick was wrong. The OP was correct in showing that the particular answer claimed as correct was wrong.

Comment: Yes he was correct in proving their answer wrong, but he chose the wrong answer for the question, as is expressed in my answer, so please read it.

Answer (score 0):

The given expression has a real root $\approx  -13.5153$ and two complex roots.

The question was set cleverly to start with, but the setter seems somehow upset.

Comment: is the last term -20 or +20? The question header suggests it is +20 when moved to the left-hand-side.

Answer (score 0):

***Hint:-***

Let,$$f(x)=x^3+12x^2-19x+20=0$$

Now,try using [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) which states that if a polynomial $f(x)$ is satisfied $f(a)$ (where $a$ is any real number),then $(x-a)$ is a factor of the given polynomial.

Now,you have two ways of solving the problem-

1. Find all the other factors by substitution and trial and error method.
2. Once you find a factor divide the polynomial of degree $3$ (as given here) by it to get the quotient as a quadratic polynomial.Now,the quadratic polynomial can be easily [mid-term factored](http://www.ask-math.com/quadratic-factorization-using-splitting-of-middle-term.html).

Hope my answer helps!!

Comment: Ok. I found that 
$$a=-4-\frac{\sqrt[3]{1008-5
   \sqrt{4551}}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{67}{\sqrt[3]{3 \left(1008-5
   \sqrt{4551}\right)}}$$ works. Now what?

Comment: I mean, you had the gall to flag B. Jenkins' answer as *very low quality*. IMO it then behooves you to deliver the goods.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The question itself is incorrect.It has no real roots and B. Jenkins post is better a comment than an answer.My answer delivers a systematic approach to solving such questions...(I hope you will not take my comment as impudence...I will take a point to delete my answer once you have read my comment)